# Not getting data from Second table

Tags: sql, ms-access

''hi all
''query is working but i am not getting data from BD table ( B_Detail )
''What am i doing wrong..??

```
SELECT CM.CM_Date AS Cdate, CM.C_MemoNo AS CmNo,0 as BookDate, 0 as LR_No, 
CM.CM_Total as CMAmt, 0 as Amt_Rcvd, 0 as ChqDDNo, 0 as ChqDDdate, 0 as Acc_Typ, 
0 as RcptNo,0 as MemoNo, 0 as M_Date, CM.CNee as conName
from (CMemo as CM
INNER JOIN ClientLedger ON (ClientLedger.CName = CM.CNee))
UNION ALL 
Select 0 as Rcpt_Date, 0 as CmNo, BD.Bdate as BookDate, BD.BNo as LR_No, 
0 as CM_Total, 0 as Amt_Rcvd, 0 as ChqDDNo, 0 as ChqDDdate, 0 as Acc_Typ, 
0 as RcptNo,BD.CST as MNo, BD.GRDate as M_Date, BD.Consignee 
from (B_Detail BD 
INNER JOIN Receipt_CLNT CM ON (CM.CNee = BD.Consignee))
UNION ALL 
SELECT Receipt_CLNT.Rcpt_Date, 0 as CmNo, 0 as BookDate, 0 as LR_No, 
0 as CM_Total, Receipt_CLNT.Amt_Rcvd as RcptAmt,Receipt_CLNT.ChqDDNo as RefNo, 
Receipt_CLNT.ChqDDdate as RefDate, Receipt_CLNT.Amt_Mode as Mode, 
Receipt_CLNT.RcptNo as RcptNo, 0 as MemoNo, 0 as MDate, Receipt_CLNT.G_Name
from Receipt_CLNT
ORDER BY Cdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify the question to just the problem part does it still not return data?

```
Select 0 as Rcpt_Date, 0 as CmNo, BD.Bdate as BookDate, BD.BNo as LR_No, 
       0 as CM_Total, 0 as Amt_Rcvd, 0 as ChqDDNo, 0 as ChqDDdate, 0 as Acc_Typ, 
       0 as RcptNo,BD.CST as MNo, BD.GRDate as M_Date, BD.Consignee 
from (B_Detail BD 
INNER JOIN Receipt_CLNT CM ON (CM.CNee = BD.Consignee))
```

If so then the join (being an inner join) is not matching any keys.
CM.CNee = BD.Consignee

Comment: Thanks for Reply, you are right. its asking me put parameter (CM.CNee) please show me how to solve this problem .

Comment: I am not sure what the question is?

Comment: i am not getting data from BD table

Comment: Do you have records in the Consignee column of the B_Detail table that match records in the CNee column of the Receipt_CLNT table. This is the join key you have specified. Being an inner join, it will only display records that exist in both tables.